# How to display number of users in object properties panel? 2.91

Tags: interface, panel, data-blocks

After updating to 2.91, I can no longer see a user number in object properties, when using *Duplicate Linked* (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>). Is it possible to make this feature work, like in previous versions?

Here's how my object data panel looks like (the number of users next to object name is now missing):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When duplicating with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> the object data is linked.

So you can see it in the *"object data properties"* part:

[image]